# A constructor containing another constructor of the same Class/Object

Tags: java, multiple-constructors

I am having a class `SomeClass` with the following member fields and the constructors

```
private int someInt;
private String someStr;
private String strTwo;

//the contructors
public SomeClass() {}

// second constructor
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr) {
    this.someInt = someInt;
    this.someStr = someStr;
}

// my emphasis here
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
    // can i do this
    new SomeClass(someInt, someStr); // that is, calling the former constructor
    this.strTwo = strTwo;
}
```

Will the third constructor create the same object as:

```
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
    this.someInt = someInt;
    this.someStr = someStr;
    this.strTwo = strTwo;
}
```

Comment: Calling another constructor is done with the this(...) keyword

Comment: what do you mean by 'self.someInt' ?? It should be 'this.someInt' I suppose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword to [call a constructor from another constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).  If you do call another constructor, then it must be the first statement in the constructor body.

```
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
    // Yes you can do this
    this(someInt, someStr); // calling the former constructor
    this.strTwo = strTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not how you have it written.

Your third constructor creates `new` object, and then sets the member variable of `strTwo` of it's `this` object. You're essentially dealing with two separate objects here. The object you `new` in the third constructor will be garbage collected because after leaving the constructor there is no reference to it.

```
//This function is called when creating a new object with three params
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
    new SomeClass(someInt, someStr); //Here you create a second new object
    //Note that the second object is not set to a variable name, so it is
    //immediately available for garbage collection
    this.strTwo = strTwo; //sets strTwo on the first object
}
```

If your goal is to create a single object that is functionally the same as one created by a two-parameter constructor, you must do this:

```
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
    this.SomeClass(someInt, someStr);
    this.strTwo = strTwo;
}
```

This will be equivalent code to doing all the member field sets in one function, with only a minor variation on how the object construction actually gets to that final product. As always, note that the objects created between these two functions will be equal but NOT the 'same' object: that is they will be pointing to different places in memory that hold the same values. 'same' can be a tricky word to use when talking about objects.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the keyword "this" in the third constructor instead:

```
public SomeClass(int someInt, String someStr, String strTwo) {
// can i do this
this(someInt, someStr); // that is, calling the former constructor
this.strTwo = strTwo;
```

}

Then it should have the same result, yes.